# Delete by Id in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Is there any one command in Mongoid to delete an object using id?

Something like,

```
ClassName.delete(:id)
```

Currently i dont see anything like that and im using,

```
obj = ClassName.find(:id)
obj.delete
```

Can it be any better?

Comment: Check my answer, Its a mogoid way. :). thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
ClassName.delete_all(conditions: { _id: BSON::ObjectId("whatevertheidis")})
```

You need the underscore in `_id` or it won't work.

Also, it may not matter, but `destroy_all` will run the model's callback methods while `delete_all` does not.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. However a small edit: ClassName.delete_all(conditions: { _id: BSON::ObjectId("whatevertheidis")})

Answer (score 3):

Another Way

```
ClassName.any_in(:_id => ["id1", "id2"]).destroy_all
```